# My ethernet controller's driver has gone missing...

Tags: drivers, ethernet

yesterday i was on the internet on my desktop PC and all of a sudden the net drops out. I search around my PC and discover that my Ethernet controller's driver is no longer installed. I have no idea what card it is as the PC is a hand me down from my step dad. in the hardware id tab is this Pci\ven_10B7&dev_9200 if that helps. please help. Also my pc is running windows 7.

Edit: Windows update, returns nothing, the hp website sends me to a driver that when i run it says there are no NIC's installed in this system that 3coms NIC upgrade program supports. Ive been looking everywhere and i cant find it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try googling for `Pci\ven_10B7&dev_9200`?

The first four hits answer your question: It is a 3Com EtherLink XL 10/100.

That is an old card. If you have an alternative internet connection try getting the driver via windows update. (E.g use wireless, tether a telephone, ...)

Else download a safe known driver. If you try to do this you might discover that 3com no longer exists as a separate firm. it has been bought by HP. Go to their website, use the search box in the upper right corner and download the driver.